# PresentViewController crash on iOS 6

Tags: ios, crash, sigabrt

i got a weird crash problem of my App. Once I enter B ViewController from A ViewController, it crash(not every time, only happened once). here is the code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];  
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];

    if( section == 0 && row == 0 && self.uidString && self.profileDic)
    {
            BViewController *bviewcontroller = [[BViewController alloc] init];
            [bviewcontroller setProfileDic:self.profileDic];
            bviewcontroller.delegate = self;
            bviewcontroller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self presentModalViewController:bviewcontroller animated:YES];
            [bviewcontroller release];
    }
}
```

and the crash log is

```
Date/Time:       2013-06-18 10:00:39.720 +0800
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.4 (10B350)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x31d3c3e2 __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39a3795e objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31d3c298 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96
3   Foundation                      0x32612f9e -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 86
4   UIKit                           0x33c37754 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 172
5   UIKit                           0x33c36fa6 -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 3394
6   UIKit                           0x33d58d9e -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 26
```

I looked for answers and some posts here said it is because "presentViewController" method of UIViewController is not available on iOS 4.3 and the solution is just to change "presentViewController" to "presentModalViewController". But that is exactly what my code did. So is there anyone who know what might happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the code implementation?

Comment: Hi, MrBr, i just post the code.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to retain your presented view controller somewhere (e.g. in an iVar). I am guessing it is getting deallocated before it shows up.

Comment: hi frasmage, I didn't use ARC but from my source code above, I don't think it is deallocated before it shows up. (and as I mentioned, this crash happen only one time )